# Можно ли ранее обозначенную числом переменную вывести из str в int?

Tags: python

Всем доброго времени суток. Появилась необходимость сделать мини метрический калькулятор. Например, из слова "*megananokilogigamicrometer*" по приставкам вывести степень конечного числа x. На примере mega имеет вид *10^6*, nano *10^-9* и так далее, в итоге получится *10^3*, нужно вывести степень 10, то есть 3. Я обозначил в коде заранее, чему равны эти переменные, но после того, как я нашел их в слове, не знаю, как вернуть в них значение из начала. Вот код:

```
tera    =12
giga    =9
mega    =6
kilo    =3
deci    =-1
centi   =-2
milli   =-3
micro   =-6
nano    =-9

words = ['tera', 'giga', 'mega', 'kilo', 'deci','centi', 'milli', 'micro', 'nano']

word = input()
ans = []

##Находим слова-приставки
for i in words:
    if i in word:
        ans.append(i)

##Находим сумму их степени       
print(sum(map(int, ans)))
```

Главный для меня вопрос - как все таки перевести приставку, которую я получил в цикле for в заданное ей значение. Опять же пример. Слово kilometer. В цикле for я получаю 'kilo' в строчке, но как эту "kilo" перевести в 3

Comment: Например, сделать словарь

Comment: Да, действительно! Спасибо Вам огромное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вам написали создайте словарь, который содержит значения для степеней, а не список

```py
words = {'tera':12, 'giga':9, 'mega':6, 'kilo':3, 'deci':-1,'centi':-2, 'milli':-3, 'micro':-6, 'nano':-9}

test = "megananokilogigamicrometer"
result = 0

for key in words.keys():
  if key in test:
    result += words[key]

print(result)

# вывод 
# 3
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вы решили мой вопрос!

Comment: @Sinka на Stackoverflow не принято говорить "спасибо". Вы можете оценить ответ и отметить его как принятый. Можно почитать здесь - [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)